# What is the minimum number of 2-to-1 muxes needed to implement a 129-to-1 mux?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

I understand that if the requirement was to implement a mux that was a power of two there is the trick where you can do do x -1, so for instance if I wanted to implement a 8-to-1 mux, I would use 7 muxes because 8 = 2<sup>3</sup> and 2<sup>3</sup> - 1 = 7. But how does that change if you wanted to implemented a mux that is not a clean power of 2?

Comment: 7× 2:1 mux have a total number of inputs that is 14. I'm surprised you can mux 128 inputs with that! Are you sure you've got that righ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller They're claiming an 8-to-1 mux with 7, not 128-to-one.

Comment: @Hearth ah shoot, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another 2:1 mux in front of your 128:1 mux; that gives you exactly 129 possible states, with the least additional components.

Comment: So in total that is 8 muxes right?

Comment: @PeraltaLearns You need a lot more than 7 2:1 muxes to get a 128:1 mux.

Comment: 2^(7) = 128 - 1 = 127 muxes needed just to get a 128:1 mux. If I wanted the 129:1 mux in the question I would need and additional mux so 128 in total?

Comment: @PeraltaLearns I think you can trust your own math well enough to not need our confirmation in this

Comment: @MarcusMüller no please I'm actually getting really confused right now.

Comment: What is there to be confused about? You've got my precise answer, you can compute the 2:1 muxes in a 128:1 mux; I think addition of 1 can't be too challenging for someone able to type a comment?

Comment: If you don't trust yourself, draw the entire circuit on a napkin for 2, 4 and 8 inputs and see that the count matches a proposed math model.  Then use that model for the large case.

Answer (score 0):

Ports  MUXes    (2:1)  ...

```
N     X                 INT((Log(N)/LOG(2)+0.5) -1 
0     0                    0
1     1                    1
2     1                    1
3     2                    2
4     2                    2
5     3                    3
```

Roundup (Log N / Log 2) = **X** = INT((Log(N)/LOG(2)+0.5) -1 for \$2^X\$

for N=129   X=8  (2:1 MUX's)